# PHP script works from shell but not from browser - shell_exec issue with Nginx and php-fpm8.0

Tags: php

I mention a very strange PHP behavior, where I run this script from shell like:
`php ./v.php` everything is work perfect, but when call the same from browser isn't work ! (no error, no warnnig) just ignore this part of code

```
if(function_exists('shell_exec')) {
echo "shell_exec is enabled";
 shell_exec("/home/dev/v.sh /mnt/volume_26 /var/www/dev.testdomain.com dev");
} else {
    echo "shell_exec is disabled";
}
```

P.S. exec is enabled
on server installed Nginx + php-fpm8.0

Any suggestions?

Comment: what you are doing in this `/home/dev/v.sh` shell script?